# Getting Amazon MWS throttling limits

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-mws

I'm using the Java MWS API from Amazon. Recently I received an *Internal Error* while requesting `GetOrder` which was due to throttling limits.

How can I determine the throttling limits?

In the [docs](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/dev_guide/DG_Throttling.html) I see

> Amazon MWS provides header values in each call response that show the hourly quota for the current operation; the number of calls remaining in tha quota; and the date and time when the quota will reset. For example:
>
> x-mws-quota-max: 3600 
> x-mws-quota-remaining: 10 
> x-mws-quota-resetsOn: Wed, 06 Mar 2013 19:07:58 GMT

But I can't figure out how to get this metadata from the response. I expected them to be in the `GetReportResponse` which I receive from calling `getReport(GetReportRequest)`. It seems this data is not present. At least I wasn't able to get them.

But what I can see from the log output is:

> org.apache.http.wire  -  << "x-mws-quota-max: 80.0"
> org.apache.http.wire  -  << "x-mws-quota-remaining: 79.0"
> org.apache.http.wire  -  << "x-mws-quota-resetsOn: 2016-01-23T09:19:00.000Z"

This data indeed seems to be present somewhere. How can I get this information from the response?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Meanwhile I hacked a bit around in the [MWS client](https://developer.amazonservices.com/doc/orders/orders/v20130901/java.html/182-0473381-7833750) sources.
And it's really the case that the quota values are not exposed via the response nor via the WebServiceClient.
So I slightly modified the source code of `MarketplaceWebServiceClient.java`to rememer the quota values for the last received response.
Somewhere around line 2100 it reads `postResponse = httpClient.execute(method, httpContext);`
and after that line I inserted

> quotaMax = postResponse.getFirstHeader("x-mws-quota-max").getValue();
>   
> quotaRemaining = postResponse.getFirstHeader("x-mws-quota-remaining").getValue();
> quotaResetsOn = postResponse.getFirstHeader("x-mws-quota-resetsOn").getValue();

This does the trick for me and I can get the quota values directly form the client.

Comment: I've been having the same issue as you: none of throttle header values are set, but when I inspect the header directly using Fiddler, I don't find them there either. Are you saying that you are receiving these header values?

Comment: Never mind. I just noticed that those response headers are only relevant to apis with an _hourly_ quota, but such header values are not provided for the basic quotas.